# Why i can't use perf event modifiers with power/energy-cores/

Tags: kernel, perf

I'm trying to read the power of the system in kernel space using the event power/energy-cores/ with the perf tool with the command below:

```
perf stat -a -e power/energy-cores/:k -I 1000 sleep 10
```

the :k is a modifier that colects the events just in kernel space like described in this doc https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial, but when i use this :k i get the error below:

```
user@dkphome:/sys/bus/event_source/devices/cpu$ sudo perf stat -a -e
power/energy-cores/:k -I 1000 sleep 30
event syntax error: '..nergy-cores/:k'
                                   \___ parser error
Run 'perf list' for a list of valid events

  Usage: perf stat [<options>] [<command>]

     -e, --event <event>   event selector. use 'perf list' to list available events
```

First i though that this event didn't support the :k modifier but i made other tests and now i think that this may be a bug or i'm trying with the wrong syntax. To test it i tried other event like below:

The cache-misses event can be called in two ways cache-misses OR cpu/cache-misses/ so i tried both with the modifier

```
user@dkphome:/sys/bus/event_source/devices/cpu$ sudo perf stat -a -e cache-misses:k -I 1000 sleep 5
#           time             counts unit events
     1.000429017            287.589      cache-misses:k                                              
     2.000828552            195.999      cache-misses:k                                              
     3.001086195            216.885      cache-misses:k                                              
     4.001438671            240.842      cache-misses:k                                              
     5.000702347            314.469      cache-misses:k                                              
user@dkphome:/sys/bus/event_source/devices/cpu$ sudo perf stat -a -e cpu/cache-misses/:k -I 1000 sleep 5
event syntax error: '..ache-misses/:k'
                                   \___ parser error
Run 'perf list' for a list of valid events

  Usage: perf stat [<options>] [<command>]

     -e, --event <event>   event selector. use 'perf list' to list available events
user@dkphome:/sys/bus/event_source/devices/cpu$ sudo perf stat -a -e cpu/cache-misses/ -I 1000 sleep 5
#           time             counts unit events
     1.000379149          1.949.866      cpu/cache-misses/                                           
     2.000628057          1.023.040      cpu/cache-misses/                                           
     3.000906500          1.284.476      cpu/cache-misses/                                           
     4.001197960            853.127      cpu/cache-misses/                                           
     5.000762257            722.242      cpu/cache-misses/
```

Someone have a clue on how could i use the :k modifier with the power/energy-cores/ event?

**Results:**
It worked without the : as pointed by the right answer, but unfortunately for me it seems not supported with the modifier.

```
user@dkphome:~$ sudo perf stat -a -e power/energy-cores/k -I 1000 sleep 5
#           time             counts unit events
     1.000099515    <not supported> Joules power/energy-cores/k                                        
     2.000246523    <not supported> Joules power/energy-cores/k                                        
     3.000440743    <not supported> Joules power/energy-cores/k                                        
     4.000673143    <not supported> Joules power/energy-cores/k                                        
     5.000722624    <not supported> Joules power/energy-cores/k                                        
user@dkphome:~$ sudo perf stat -a -e power/energy-cores/ -I 1000 sleep 5
 #           time             counts   unit events
     1.000128209               0,19 Joules power/energy-cores/                                         
     2.000257170               0,25 Joules power/energy-cores/                                         
     3.000406715               0,26 Joules power/energy-cores/                                         
     4.000571140               0,20 Joules power/energy-cores/                                         
     5.000711815               1,01 Joules power/energy-cores/                                         
     5.000882867               0,00 Joules power/energy-cores/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the first step when you start measuring any event with `perf` commands, is to run `perf list` and check if the event `power/energy cores` is supported by your system. I will give an example running perf list on my system.

`~/linux-4.11.3/tools/perf$ ./perf list`

`List of pre-defined events (to be used in -e):`

`branch-instructions OR branches                    [Hardware event]`

`branch-misses                                      [Hardware event]`

`power/energy-cores/                                [Kernel PMU event]`

That way, you will become sure if measurement of the event power/energy-cores is actually supported by your system.

Once this is confirmed, you should use the below syntax to measure this event:

`./perf stat -a -e power/energy-cores/ -I 1000 sleep 30`  (not :k or not :u)

Edit #1:

You could have used a :k or :u if you could specify the event `power/energy-cores` like below :-

`./perf stat -a -e energy-cores:k -I 1000 sleep 30` (but `perf` cannot recognize the `energy-cores` event unless you specify the fully qualified event name like this : `power/energy-cores`).

But as I have suggested in my 2nd edit, these counters do not support user-space and kernel-space separation anyway.

Edit #2:

Unfortunately these **RAPL** counters do not separate the values based on kernel space or the user space. Moreover, the Performance Monitoring Unit related to these events cannot perform sampling as well.

This is the proof in code :

[arch/x86/events/intel/rapl.c](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/events/intel/rapl.c#L400)

Moreover, you can read the below patch document to understand :-

[RAPL patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/3120811/)

Comment: Hi @Arnabjyoti Kalita you are right the problem was the : the couter power/energy-cores/ is supported by my system but, unfurtunatly seems that not with the k or any other modifier.

Do you have any clue on how these modifiers are supported? I need it so much, that i need to try to add the support myself if there aren't other way.

Comment: Hi @Leandro, what kind of messages do you receive when you run the perf stat command ? How do you know even though the system supports this event, you are not getting correct/proper values ?

Comment: I added the results in the end of my question, the event is presnt in perf list and it returns values without the modifier, but what i need is the values separated by kernel and user space.

Comment: Hi @LeandroSilva, unfortunately you cannot separate these counters based on kernel and user space values. I have added some more details to my answer.